# Can the input value of the button be an image which changes when toggled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button which shows and hides an element when clicked. It also changes the value to 'Show' or 'Hide'. I would like to have an image (along with the text) in the value attribute of the button to change along with the text when I toggle.

EDIT: I updated my codepen with solutions advised. There are however, other issues to solve there.
Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/headofclowns/pen/KKVOjZE) showing what I mean visually

Here is a snippet.

```js
function toggle(ele) {
  var cont = document.getElementById('proj-details');
  if (cont.style.display == 'flex') {
    cont.style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Show details';
  } else {
    cont.style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById(ele.id).value = 'Hide details';
  }
}
```

```css
.spec-proj-briefshowhide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.spec-proj-briefshowhide input {
  padding: 0.4em;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.05em solid blue;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.spec-proj-briefshowhide img {
  max-width: 10em;
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="spec-proj-briefshowhide">
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Hide details" id="bt" onclick="toggle(this)">
  </p>
  <div style="display:flex;" id="proj-details">
    <div>
      <p>Brief:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>So I have this show/hide toggle button working to my liking.</li>
        <li>What I would also like is to have an image along with text in the button.</li>
        <li>You see..? I have the value attribute of the button changing as I click on it to toggle.</li>
        <li>What I would want is an image with open-eyes to represent the displayed element and another image close-eyes to represent when I toggle the button to hide the details. Check what I mean by close and open eyes before thinking I am crazy.</li>
        <li>I noticed people use image background, especially when they want a button to look like a play button, pause button or a record button. These are static buttons and do not change.</li>
        <li>I want a change of image instead, because I have two images which need to be toggled back and forth</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Here are the two images for the curious kind.<img src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png" alt="OPENEYE" border="0">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yPhD6HF/CLOSEEYE.png" alt="CLOSEEYE" border="0">
  </p>
  <button>Show<img src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png" alt="OPENEYE" border="0">details</button>
  <button>Hide<img src="https://i.ibb.co/yPhD6HF/CLOSEEYE.png" alt="CLOSEEYE" border="0">details</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the name and value fields in input is for submittal of a form to the server.

So as far as setting an image in a value field - you could include an image href in the value field, but it wouldn't automatically render the image. You can't include an image and a text value.

What I suggest you do if you want to have both and to submit both to the server is to use an input type=hidden field with the image url, plus a separate img tag for the visual image, like

```
   <p>
   <table><tr>
   <td id="imgTD"><input type="hidden" name="imgField" id="imgField" /> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td>
   <input type="button" value="Hide details" id="bt" onclick="toggle(this)">
   </td></tr>
   </table>
   </p>
```

Putting together my code example, I notice that you haven't given your button a name. If the button is not for form purposes, you might want to use the *button* tag instead of an input

Comment: Okay, So I could let the value field be just text and have a image right beside the button and have it toggled.

Comment: @fullfledgedclown yes. Does this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I got to know that I cant insert an image into a value field and expect it to change. Though it would be great to have it working that way. It would be so easy! Here is an updated codepen. I have other issues which are specified as bullet points in my codepen. But I guess I should make another post asking to solve that. https://codepen.io/headofclowns/pen/KKVOjZE?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

there is another simple way to just the image src :

```
const imgBtn = document.getElementById("eye")
function toggleImg(){
    let cont = document.getElementById('proj-details');
      if (cont.style.display == 'flex') {
        cont.style.display = 'none';
        imgBtn.src = "https://i.ibb.co/yPhD6HF/CLOSEEYE.png"

      } else {
        cont.style.display = 'flex';
        imgBtn.src = "https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png"

      }
}

imgBtn.addEventListener("click",toggleImg)
```

```
<div class="spec-proj-briefshowhide">
      <img id="eye" src="https://i.ibb.co/NjRDMFS/OPENEYE.png" alt="OPENEYE" border="0">
   <p>
   <input type="button" value="Hide details" id="bt" onclick="toggle(this)">
   </p>
    
  <div style="display:flex;" id="proj-details">
 <p>Brief:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>So I have this show/hide toggle button working to my liking.</li>
    <li>What I would also like is to have an image along with text in the button.</li>
    <li>You see..? I have the value attribute of the button changing as I click on it to toggle.</li>
    <li>What I would want is an image with open-eyes to represent the displayed element and another image close-eyes to represent when I toggle the button to hide the details. Check what I mean by close and open eyes before thinking I am crazy.</li>
    <li>I noticed people use image background, especially when they want a button to look like a play button, pause button or a record button. These are static buttons and do not change.</li>
    <li>I want a change of image instead, because I have two images which need to be toggled back and forth.</li>
 
 </ul>
</div>
  <p>Here are the two images for the curious kind.</p>
</div>
```